# Set default value for dynamic choice field

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form that asks the user to enter in their zip code. Once they do it sends them to another form where there is a field called 'pickup_date'. This gets the value of the zip from the previous field and gets all of the available pickup_dates that match that zip code into a ChoiceField. I set all of this within the **init** of the model form.

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):

    super(ExternalDonateForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    if kwargs:
        zip = kwargs['initial']['zip']
        self.fields['pickup_date'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices = self.get_dates(zip))


    elif self.errors:
        zip = self.data['zip']
        self.fields['pickup_date'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices = self.get_dates(zip))
```

The problem I have is when there are other errors on the form. I use the `elif self.errors` to regenerate the possible choices but it doesn't default to the original selected option. It goes back and defaults to the first choice. How can I make it so it's default option on form errors is what was originally posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work after playing around for a while. Above, I was setting all the dynamic choices with a get_dates() function that returned a tuple. Instead of doing that I returned a field object like this using a customized [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) instead of a regular ChoiceField....

```
class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.date.strftime('%a %b %d, %Y')
```

Dates function

```
def get_dates(self,zip):        
            routes = Route.objects.filter(zip=zip).values_list('route',flat=True)
            pickups = self.MyModelChoiceField(queryset = PickupSchedule.objects.filter(         
                    current_count__lt=F('specials'),
                    route__in=routes,
                ).order_by('date')
            )    

            if not pickups:
                pickups = (('----','No Pickups Available At This Time'),)

            return pickups
```

in the **init** i set the value for `self.fields['pickup_date']` like so..

```
self.fields['pickup_date'] = self.get_dates(zip)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change self.fields['pickup_date'] to self.fields['pickup_date'].initial and see if that helps.

Comment: No dice - that removes the <select> tag from the form and back into a Char Field...on both conditions